# how to connect ViewModel in Fragment again after callback from viewholder

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, viewmodel, android-viewholder

I made a callback by interface from a viewholder to the Fragment that has created the recyclerviewadapter with that viewholder inside.
Now I'm having trouble to connect to the viewmodel (of that fragment) with:

```java
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ViewModelClass.class);
```

because of a null pointer exception :( 
I can’t catch up to the activity again after that callback from the viewholder…

How would you solve that problem?

code:
recyclerviewadapter & viewholder:
public class BoxRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public String TAG = BoxRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
Context context;
private List<Car> carList;
private CallbackBox callbackBox;

// boxType: 1 = cars | 2 = damage
private int boxType = 0;


// empty constructor
BoxRecyclerViewAdapter(){

}

// constuctor to create car boxes
public BoxRecyclerViewAdapter boxRecyclerViewAdapterCar(Context _context, List<Car> _tempList) {

    this.carList = _tempList;
    this.context = _context;
    // hide buttons
    this.boxType = 1;

    return this;
}

// constuctor to create damage boxes
public BoxRecyclerViewAdapter boxRecyclerViewAdapterDamage(Context _context, List<Car> _tempList) {

    this.carList = _tempList;
    this.context = _context;
    // show buttons
    this.boxType = 2;

    return this;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    /*
    if ( callbackBox == null ){
        Log.d(TAG, "mike: in BoxRecycler - callback = null " );
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "mike: in BoxRecycler - callback = NOT NULL " + callbackBox.toString() );
    }
```

*/

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.box_layout, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view, this.callbackBox);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Car UploadInfo = carList.get(position);

    holder.lb_title.setText(UploadInfo.getManuf());
    holder.lb1.setText(UploadInfo.getModell());
    holder.lb2.setText(UploadInfo.getIdentno());
    holder.lb3.setText(UploadInfo.getYear());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return carList.size();
}


// register callback regarding the box listener with the ViewHolder Method
public void registerCallBackBoxListener( CallbackBox _callbackBox ){

    //Log.d(TAG, "mike: callback register - complete");
    this.callbackBox = _callbackBox;

}


// ******************* class ViewHolder *********************

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Context context;
    private CallbackBox callbackBox;

    private TextView lb_title;
    private TextView lb1;
    private TextView lb2;
    private TextView lb3;
    private TextView lb1_desc;
    private TextView lb2_desc;
    private TextView lb3_desc;
    private Button bt_accept;
    private Button bt_reject;
    private ImageButton ibt_menu_edit;
    private ImageButton ibt_menu_del;
    private LinearLayout layout_box_buttons;



    private ViewHolder(final View itemView, CallbackBox _callbackBox)  {
        super(itemView);

        this.callbackBox = _callbackBox;
        this.context = itemView.getContext();

        lb_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb_title);
        lb1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb1);
        lb2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb2);
        lb3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb3);
        lb1_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb1_desc);
        lb2_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb2_desc);
        lb3_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lb3_desc);
        bt_accept = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_accept);
        bt_reject = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_reject);
        ibt_menu_edit = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibt_menu_edit);
        ibt_menu_del = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibt_menu_del);
        layout_box_buttons = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_box_buttons);


        // configure box layout
        switch (boxType) {
            // car
            case 1:
                // hide the layout with the buttons
                layout_box_buttons.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                lb1_desc.setText(R.string.txt_car_modell);
                lb2_desc.setText(R.string.txt_car_identno);
                lb3_desc.setText(R.string.txt_car_year);
                break;
            // damage
            case 2:
                layout_box_buttons.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                break;
        }





        // ******************** Listeners ****************

        // start edit fragment
        ibt_menu_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "menu button edit clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Log.d(TAG, "mike: in edit onClick Listener - toString: " + callbackBox.toString() );


                callbackBox.onCarEdit( lb2.getText().toString()  );

            }
        });


        // start delete (path to identNo)
        ibt_menu_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "menu button del clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                callbackBox.onCarDelete( lb2.getText().toString() );
            }
        });



        // onClickListeners - Buttons
        // start accept
        bt_accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "accept button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // sharing reject
        bt_reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "reject button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

---

Fragment & callback:
public class FragmentCarDetailRequest extends Fragment implements CallbackBox{

```
public String TAG = FragmentCarDetailRequest.class.getSimpleName();

public ViewModelClass viewModelClass;

// Creating RecyclerView & adapter
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

// Creating Progress dialog
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Creating List of Events class
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

private String userUid;

public static FragmentCarDetailRequest newInstance() {
    return new FragmentCarDetailRequest();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_recyclerview, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup any handles to view objects here

    this.viewModelClass = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ViewModelClass.class);
    userUid = viewModelClass.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    // Assign id to RecyclerView.
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    // Assign activity this to progress dialog.
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Daten werden geladen");
    progressDialog.show();


    Log.d(TAG, "mike: starting livedata request ");
    LiveData<DataSnapshot> liveData = viewModelClass.getDataSnapshotLiveData("cars", userUid );
    liveData.observe(this, new Observer<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot != null ){
                carList.clear();

                // retrieve the server content to add it to the list
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {

                    Car car = postSnapshot.getValue(Car.class);
                    carList.add(car);
                }


                BoxRecyclerViewAdapter boxRecyclerViewAdapter = new BoxRecyclerViewAdapter();

                // register callbacks & RecyclerViewAdapter
                CallbackBox callbackBox = new FragmentCarDetailRequest();
                boxRecyclerViewAdapter.registerCallBackBoxListener( callbackBox );
                adapter = boxRecyclerViewAdapter.boxRecyclerViewAdapterCar( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), carList );
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

         progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCarDelete(String _identNo) {

    Log.d(TAG, "mike: got callback to delete car..." + viewModelClass.getCurrentUser().getUid());

}
```

}

---

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

08-03 16:05:49.623 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wendtmichael.app2repair, PID: 6833
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.wendtmichael.app2repair.ViewModelClass.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
        at com.wendtmichael.app2repair.FragmentCarDetailRequest.onCarDelete(FragmentCarDetailRequest.java:173)
        at com.wendtmichael.app2repair.BoxRecyclerViewAdapter$ViewHolder$2.onClick(BoxRecyclerViewAdapter.java:193)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5264)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21297)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)

Comment: This question is not clear enough. Do you mind posting your viewmodel, error log and fragment codes here.

Comment: got the reason....: i made a new instance with this:
                // register callbacks & RecyclerViewAdapter
                CallbackBox callbackBox = new FragmentCarDetailRequest();
                boxRecyclerViewAdapter.registerCallBackBoxListener( callbackBox );

within that new instance i couldn't find any variables nor the viewmodel...

i had to change like this:
 // register callbacks
        boxRecyclerViewAdapter.registerCallBackBoxListener(this);